# Is it possible to NotifyChanged on an ObservableCollection property via CollectionChanged event?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

Is it possible for me to have an ObservableCollection as a property in a class but subscribe to it's CollectionChanged event and call OnPropertyChanged on the ObservableCollection property as to update a UI binding to the collection? –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of binding to the collection and using a converter you can expose a read-only ItemNames property. In the Items.CollectionChanged event handler you raise a PropertyChanged event for the ItemNames property

```
public class ViewModel
{

      public ViewModel()
      {
           Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
           Items.CollectionChanged += (o, e) => NotifyPropertyChanged("ItemNames");
      }
      public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; private set; }
      public string ItemNames { get { return String.Join(",", Items); } }
}
```

Comment: What if the class is created using svcutil. Would I generate the readonly on the client side. What if I'm recieving the data from the service rather then generating in on the client side. Where would i attached the events?

Comment: Also the Collection that is being changed is Nested within another collection.

Comment: I Got it to work by setting a constructor that accepts its own type as an argument in then copies the values and create a new ObservableCollection and attaches the NotifyPropertyChanged call to the CollectionChanged event as you specified. The string is updated. I only use the constructor once like this hence the reason it is safe to create new collection. I'm not sure if this is the most effective way but it is working. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but usually you wouldn't want to do something like that because of the overhead. If you use controls with an `ItemsSource` they know how to handle `CollectionChanged` without re-creating everything.

Comment: I'm binding that property in DataColumn of a Grid and using an IValueConverter to convert the ObservableCollection to a Comma Seperated string. I definantly know this isn't the way to go as i can't filter etc. I know this can be done as a read-only property in my class how do I Notify that the Read-Only string property has changed since the collection has changed?

Comment: @ChristopherLeach: Just subscribe to the CollectionChanged event and fire a PropertyChanged event for the property holding the string.

Comment: Only hickup is that the class is generated from a WCF service. I have tried generating a partial class client side with the read-only string property and attaching the CollectionChanged event handler however this won't be seralized across the service. Should I inherit the WCF classes in a new class and  link up the events there?

Comment: Also the Collection that is being changed is Nested within another collection.